# Inserting Value from CSV file to Sybase Table

Tags: sql, csv, sybase

I'm trying to insert the value from a CSV file (with 5 columns) into a Sybase table (with 3 columns). I have tried a fair amount of commands such as BULK INSERT, LOAD TABLE, INPUT INTO, but all gives me error messages.

---

EDIT:

I am using the Sybase ASE. The table contains 3 columns, with the values being INT, varchar, and varchar. The file has columns A,B,C,D,E, and columns B,C,D corrolate to the table's columns.

Some of the command I have tried:

BULK INSERT table

FROM 'C:\temp\file.csv'

WITH (FORMAT='CSV')

error message: Incorrect Syntax near the word 'BULK'

---

LOAD TABLE table

FROM 'C:\temp\file.csv'

FORMAT CSV

error message: Incorrect Syntax near the word 'TABLE'

---

INPUT INTO table

FROM 'C:\temp\file.csv'

FORMAT ASCII

error message: Incorrect Syntax near the word 'INTO'

---

Some of the documentations that I used:

https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/BABDFIEC.htm

https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1530/doc/html/san1281564935243.html

Comment: "error messages" - do you have examples?
**Check** -
Column lengths on table can accommodate values / Column Data Types on table are not strongly typed (use varchars to simplify loading)

Comment: Hello, most of the error messages are somewhere along the lines of: Sybase Database Error: Incorrect Synttax near the word "TABLE", but I have followed the exact syntax provided by the Sybase Documentation, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? please update the question with sample contents of the CSV file, the table structure, the commands you've attempted and the associated error messages for each command; also provide the link to the 'Sybase Documentation' you're referring to (the 4x Sybase RDBMS products have different SQL dialects and/or commands so it's not clear at this point if you're referring to the correct set of documenation for your particular Sybase RDBMS product)

Comment: Hello, I've added some relevent information.

Comment: all of these commands are invalid in Sybase ASE; the 2nd link points to documentation for the Sybase IQ product (this is not the same as Sybase ASE); as for the 1st link ... the `input` command is a client-side command that's only available in the isql GUI and is not an actual Sybase ASE command (see [the 1st paragraph at the top of the chapter](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/BABDFIEC.htm)

Comment: what tool/software/application are you using when you're running your commands?

Comment: while it may be possible to use `create existing table / external file` to access the file, there are several caveats to this approach (eg, permissions to access external files, data file must reside on same host as ASE instance, etc); you'll likely have better luck using the OS-level `bcp` command (see the [Utility Guide](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570/html/utilityguide/title.htm) for more details on `bcp`) ...

Comment: though `bcp` isn't very smart when it comes to working with CSV files (eg, has problems distinguishing between a comma as delimiter vs comma as data), and it's not straight forward to reference a subset of columns from the input file (ie, may have to pre-parse the file to strip out unwanted columns)

Comment: the other option is to try uising a tool/application that's CSV aware (eg, isql GUI? some of the SQLServer GUI tools; other 3rd party tools), ie, software that can parse the CSV file and generate the corresponding (bulk) inserts to Sybase ASE